# How to show keyboard on click in titanium android app

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I am having problem in showing keyboard on click.

I can hide keyboard using

```
textfield.blur();
```

OR

```
Ti.UI.Android.hideSoftKeyboard();
```

But for showing keyboard i am facing problem.

I have also tried

```
textfield.focus();
```

But it's not working.

Can anybody please provide solution ?

Thanks

Comment: textfield.blur(); does not work in 3.5.0 GA

Comment: Ok thanks.. but i am able to hide it. I want to show keyboard on click

Comment: Have you tried like this " textField.softKeyboardOnFocus = Titanium.UI.Android.SOFT_KEYBOARD_SHOW_ON_FOCUS; "

Comment: I am able to resolve it using this. $.message.setSoftKeyboardOnFocus(Ti.UI.Android.SOFT_KEYBOARD_SHOW_ON_FOCUS);
     $.message.focus();